# Erro de parâmetros inválidos ao fazer o PDO realizar ação

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estou tentando aprender a usar PDO, então eu já mexi MUITO procurando de tudo pra entender ele. Dai eu estou num ponto que me deixou bastante confuso.

Eu tenho o seguindo código, ele é o: **_conecta_banco.php**

```
<?php
class conectar_banco {

    var $host        = 'localhost';
    var $usuario     = 'root';
    var $senha       = '';
    var $banco       = 'trabalho_kinccal';

    var $pdo         = null;
    var $buscaSegura = null;
    var $qtdeLinhas  = null;

    // Cria a função para Conectar ao Banco MySQL
    function conecta() {
        try{
            $this->pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=".$this->host.";dbname=".$this->banco,$this->usuario,$this->senha);
            $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    // Método de Busca
    public function buscar($table, $where = null, $order = null, $limit = null) {
        $busca = 'SELECT * FROM '.$table;
            if($where != null) $busca .= ' WHERE :where';
            if($order != null) $busca .= ' ORDER BY :order';
            if($limit != null) $busca .= ' LIMIT :limit';

        $buscaSegura = $this->pdo->prepare($busca);
        $buscaSegura->bindValue(":where",$where);
        $buscaSegura->bindValue(":order",$order);
        $buscaSegura->bindParam(":limit",$limit);
        $buscaSegura->execute();

        // Salvar número de registros
        echo $this->buscaSegura = $buscaSegura->rowCount();
    }

    function inserir($tabela, $valores, $campos = null){
        $inserir = 'INSERT INTO ' . $tabela;
        if($campos != null) $inserir .= ' ('.$campos.')';
        for($i = 0; $i < count($valores); $i++){
            if( is_string($valores[$i]) ) $valores[$i] = '"'.$valores[$i].'"';
        }
        $valores = implode(',',$valores);
        $inserir .= ' VALUES ('.$valores.')';

        $inserirSeguro = $this->pdo->prepare($inserir);
        //$inserirSeguro->bindValue(
    }

    function qtdeLinhas() {
        return $this->buscaSegura;
    }
}
?>
```

Bom, daí eu criei um **index.php**, e ele é assim:

```
<?php
include ("class/_conecta_banco.php");
$data = new conectar_banco();
$data->conecta();
$data->buscar('usuarios','','','1');
$data->qtdeLinhas();

?>
```

Bem, não testei esse meu **inserir** mas já sei que não deve rodar. Vou direto ao ponto.
Quando vou abrir o **index.php** ele da o seguinte erro:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens' in C:\xampp\htdocs\PDO\class_conecta_banco.php:34 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\PDO\class_conecta_banco.php(34): PDOStatement->execute() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\PDO\index.php(5): conectar_banco->buscar('usuarios', '', '', '1') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\PDO\class_conecta_banco.php on line 34

Mas se eu alterar essa linha no **index.php**

```
$data->buscar('usuarios','','','1');
```

para: (só tirei o valor)

```
$data->buscar('usuarios','','','');
```

ele chega a mostrar resultado.

No método **buscar** eu botei condições onde eu iria construir a linha de comando SQL, mas não entendo porque quando vou usar, ele não quer usar! Deu pra entender? Se eu usar o **echo** alí depois dos **if** ele mostrará que está formando a **string** que será usada logo abaixo.

**ADD:**
Eu pensei que poderia fazer meio que um 'construtor global', entende?
Acha que tem algum modo deu fazer isso? Terei mesmo que criar todos as possibilidades de SELECT que eu quiser usar?

Comment: A palavra `var` era usada no php4 para definir membros da classe, no php5 utilize os modificadores de acesso: `private`, `protected` e `public`. [manual - visibilidade](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.visibility.php)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eu vejo alguns problemas (talvez não todos) no seu uso do PDO:

- **Parâmetros servem para substituir valores, não trechos de uma cláusula.**
  Ou seja: você não pode usar `WHERE :where`, precisa de algo como `WHERE coluna = :valor`. E você não pode dizer `ORDER BY :order` e passar um nome de coluna.
- **Você não pode associar um parâmetro ao *statement* e não usá-lo dentro do statement.**
  Ou seja: se você usa `$buscaSegura->bindValue(":valor", $valor);`, o nome `:valor` precisa aparecer na query. Essa é a causa do erro que você está vendo:

  > Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Comment: Eu pensei que poderia fazer meio que um 'construtor global', entende?
Acha que tem algum modo deu fazer isso? Terei mesmo que criar todos as possibilidades de SELECT que eu quiser usar?

Comment: Você pode sim fazer isso, mas não pode usar `:where` para o `WHERE` inteiro. Monte partes do SQL com PHP, e use os placeholders do PDO somente para valores.

Comment: Ou seja, só posso usar os `:nome` se eles forem realmente usados, certo? Não podem ficar vazios.

Comment: Isso @Fabrizio, só se usar.